# Stripe connection error Cloudflare worker

Tags: node.js, stripe-payments, cloudflare-workers

I am getting "Error: An error occurred with our connection to Stripe." at paymentIntents.create in the cloudflare worker.

Here is the code:

```
addEventListener('fetch', event => {
      event.respondWith(handleRequest(event.request))
    })
    /**
     * Respond with hello worker text
     * @param {Request} request
     */
    async function handleRequest(request) {
      const stripe = require('stripe')('Stripkey');
    
      const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 1000,
        currency: 'cad',
        payment_method_types: ['card'],
        receipt_email: 'jenny.rosen@example.com',
      });
      return new Response('Hello worker!', {
        headers: { 'content-type': 'text/plain' },
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

[Cloudflare workers don't fully support Node.js](https://blog.cloudflare.com/node-js-support-cloudflare-workers/) and the error you're seeing is due to the fact that Stripe's Node library depends on Node-specific APIs to work.  [Stripe is working on a fix](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/issues/997) and once that fix is released this should start working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

An update for anyone like myself who still came across this issue with Cloudflare Workers and Stripe and finds this post, Cloudflare **does** support the Stripe SDK now, all it takes is a slight tweak to the initialisation.

Just need to tell it to use a httpFetch method instead:

```
const stripe = Stripe(STRIPE_API_KEY, {
  httpClient: Stripe.createFetchHttpClient()
});
```

https://blog.cloudflare.com/announcing-stripe-support-in-workers/